# Laravel dynamic property not working

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent, dynamic-properties

I'm using the eloquent ORM in Laravel with a `hasMany` relationship.

when I run:

```
Level::find(1)->lessons()->get();
```

It works fine, but when I use the dynamic property like so:

```
Level::find(1)->lessons
```

It just returns results for the `level` instead of the `lessons`.

Do I need another setting somewhere?

**EDIT:** Here are the models:

```
class Level extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'levels';

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Lesson');
    }
}

class Lesson extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'lessons';

    public function level()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Level');
    }
}
```

Comment: added the models, it's nothing special, just following the documentation, not sure if I'm missing some other param or setting to make it work.

Comment: That's bizarre, everything is correct.

Comment: Ya, I'm really not doing anything special here and the `get()` call works just fine.  It returns no errors, nothing, it just doesn't run.  If I echo out the last query it shows the query for fetching the `level` rather than the `lessons` for that level.

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913560/laravel-4-how-to-access-reverse-one-to-many-relation/19015323#19015323).

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem, turns out I had a column on the table that had the same name as the relationship I set up.

Make sure you don't have a column in the model that has the same name as the relationsip method you are trying to load.

EDIT: I also noticed laravel has problems with undescores (_) in relationship names, so don't put an _ in the methodname or else it won't work.

Comment: Should be marked as correct. Tested and it's true, at least in Laravel 4

Comment: This holds true in 5.2; the column name will override the dynamic property.

Comment: i also had the same problem. in my case `author` didn't worked. after i changed it to `creator` the relation worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to eager load the relationship.

`Level::with('lessons')->find(1)->lessons;` should work.

If you want to load this relationship every time, you should add this line to `Level` model.

`protected $with = array('lessons');`