# Laravel 4, how to access reverse one-to-many relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Code:

```
<?php
class Catering extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'catering';
    public $timestamps = FALSE;

    public function offers() {
        return $this->hasMany('Offer', 'cid');
    }
}

class Offer extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'catering_offer';
    public $timestamps = FALSE;

    public function catering() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Catering');
    }
}
```

I am able to do

```
$offers = Catering::find(1)->offers;
```

**but**, the inverse is not working:

```
$catering = Offer::find(1)->catering;
```

is always returning NULL. Database has the right values.

Offer table has 2 columns:

> primary(id), int(cid)

that references catering.id.

**The question:**
How can i access the reverse side of this relation?

Comment: Without seeing the SQL that is being generated I cant say for sure. But have you tried to use `$this->belongsTo('Catering', 'cid');` as I think your use is looking for the column `catering_id` in your `offer` table.

Comment: @carbontwelve i think you're right

Answer (score 2):

You said that, `I am able to do`

```
$offers = Catering::find(1)->offers;
```

and in your `Catering` model you have

```
public function offers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Offer', 'cid');
}
```

It seems like you've defined a different foreign key here (`cid`) to use it instead of the default one that `laravel` basically supposed to use, so, to do the reverse relation you have to do the same thing in your `Offer` model's `catering` function

```
public function catering() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Catering', 'cid');
}
```

In the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many), it says that, you may override the conventional foreign key by passing a second argument to the `hasMany` method, like

```
return $this->hasMany('Offer', 'custom_key');
```

Same way, to define the inverse of the relationship on the `Offer` model, you can use the `belongsTo` method, like

```
return $this->belongsTo('Catering', 'custom_key'); // cid
```